# Install Lotus Notes server

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I can't find it on IBM's website. Neither in other sources. 
Could someone tell me where do I find the Lotus Notes server installation? Or is it possible to configure it in the cloud?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has sold IBM Notes, IBM Domino (and other collaboration products) to HCL. You can download the server installation file from the [HCL download portal](https://hclsoftware.flexnetoperations.com/flexnet/operationsportal/logon.do) (using proper credentials).

Comment: Thanks Per. That's the correct source.